the kernel for desktop appears to have died. it will restart automatically. [JupyterLab][Matplotlib]
when I run the code below in Jupyter, the error I get is "Kernel Crashed".
sns.pairplot(df,kind = "reg");
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ad = pd.read_csv("reading_data/Advertising.csv", usecols =[1, 2, 3, 4])
df = ad.copy()
df.head()

sns.pairplot(df,kind = "reg");

My own code is above. But I think there is a problem with Matplot.I tried the following steps
conda install numpy and conda install -c intel mkl
My GPU memory is fine
conda install -c anaconda keras --it didn't work for me
conda install matplotlib and conda install seaborn-- it didn't work for me

I tried pairplot with latest matplotlib and seaborn on iris dataset provided in seaborn, no problem. I'd suggest you to try with a smaller dataset and see if it is caused by insufficient memory. If the issue persists on smaller dataset, please provide your dataset along with the versions of your python/matplotlib/seaborn and system information in your question.

I've encountered a similar issue when running a Jupyter Notebook in AWS SageMaker.
In my case, it was caused by an outlier in the data: in a range of integers that was supposed to be between 0 and 5, there was a value of 2 million. Thish was causing the pairplot calculation to crash. Once I removed the extreme outlier, the issue was resolved.
Hope this helps!
